# How to Assign Schema After Load In Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Suppose I have a code like this

```
REGISTER 'SomeSript.jar'

RAW_DATA = LOAD '/home/pig/input/'  as (linearray:chararray);

FILTER_RAW_DATA = FILTER RAW_DATA BY com.pig.CustomFilter(RAW_DATA);
```

<--

Here I want to assign the ALAISE 'FILTER_RAW_DATA' with a schema.

EG : (name:chararray,pos:chararray,location:chararray,status:chararray) ,    which Ideally we do during load time, I want to assign it after the Filter Step.

-->

```
KEY_GROUP = GROUP FILTER_RAW_DATA BY location;

STORE KEY_GROUP into 'Output';
```

How Can I assign Schema After the Filter Operation for my GROUP By To Work.

Can We write a custom function For Group-by as well, just as I had written for Filtration above as CustomFilter.

Waiting for the answers.

Thanks in Advance
Cheers :)

Comment: Use a separate foreach ... generate... statement. E.g. `FILTER_RAW_DATA = foreach FILTER_RAW_DATA generate (chararray)bla as name, (chararray)blubb as pos ...` That of course requires you to already have separated the rows into the desired amount of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success in the past using REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL to extract typed tuples from a chararray.

TYPED_FILTER_RAW_DATA = FOREACH FILTER_RAW_DATA GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'REGEX') AS (name:chararray,pos:chararray,location:chararray,status:chararray);

One caveat is that if you need to type to a numeric data type another GENERATE statement is required where you need to explicitly cast to the type. For instance if status was an INT this would fail (TEST = FILTER TYPED_FILTER_RAW_DATA BY status = 0;)

You would first need to:
TEST = FOREACH TYPED_FILTER_RAW_DATA GENERATE ..., (int)tuple_0.status as status;

STRSPLIT can also be used if your data is nicely formatted.